# How to get the number of frames per second recorded during skeletal tracking

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, kinect-sdk

Anyone know how to get the number of frames per second recorded during skeletal tracking with Kinect V2 using C# in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Use a Timer or the timestamp of the frame to get frames in an interval of time or frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PerformanceCounter (from System.Diagnostics) that tracks the "System Up time" to have the program report only once per second, then have an integer that increments at each frame, but gets reset after the value is reported. This should give you an accurate framerate counter.